# Web browser cached information still protected by SSL?

Tags: ssl, https

We are using a secure application which uses https/ssl that claim the data is secure at rest. On the hosting server it is, safely locked away in a database. But I was wondering if on the client end does the web browser which caches the information also keep that information secure? What would stop me from accessing the web content from the local folder? Could you really make this claim on a web hosted solution?

Answer (score 0):

SSL/TLS/HTTPS do not protect data at rest but only data during communication. And while the data might be locked away in a database on a server side they are accessible in plain there at least for some time, i.e. after TLS decryption and probably also for processing outside the database.

Data are also not protected by TLS at the client side. They are accessible in plain in the browser and they are stored in plain in the browsers cache - unless caching is explicitly disabled for these data. The details on how data from the cache can be accessed depends on the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that answer it perfectly.